# Figuring out RGB or HEX color from xcolor

Tags: beamer, color

I have defined a color using:

```
\definecolor{canvascolor}{rgb}{0.643,0.690,0.843}
```

Then this is used with this command like `canvascolor!75!white` from `xcolor`. This is actually done in the `beamer` theme `wkbeamer`.

I know the mix of these two colors but how do I output the RGB color of this to match in a paint program. This I figure should be easy. I looked through the `xcolor` manual and couldn't find how to do this. I also looked through to just see how it determines or algorithm it uses for the new RGB color from the mix but didn't see this. I didn't read the whole manual but from a quick look through I couldn't find the algorithm for this or tried outputting the color with a couple commands but none I could get working.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `\extractcolorspec` macro will define a macro that contains the specification for a color; we can use it and the companion `\convertcolorspec` to define a macro containing the specifications for another model:

```
\definecolor{canvascolor}{rgb}{0.643,0.690,0.843}
\extractcolorspec{canvascolor!75!white}{\test}
\expandafter\convertcolorspec\test{HTML}\test
```

Now `\test` will expand to `BBC4E1`.

The first definition of `\test` will be `{rgb}{0.73225,0.7675,0.88225}` so this is good for putting it after `\convertcolorspec`, but we have to expand it first.

Use two different macros if you also need to keep the first specification around.

We can implement this in a function

```
\newcommand{\getColorSpec}[3][\getColorSpecTemp]{%
  \extractcolorspec{#3}\getColorSpecTemp
  \expandafter\convertcolorspec\getColorSpecTemp{#2}#1}
```

With `\getColorSpec{HTML}{canvascolor!75!white}` the specification will be stored in `\getColorSpecTemp`; with

```
\getColorSpec[\HTMLcolor]{HTML}{canvascolor!75!white}
```

the same specification will be stored in `\HTMLcolor`.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{canvascolor}{rgb}{0.643,0.690,0.843}
\colorlet{canvas75}{canvascolor!75!white}
\begin{document}
\noindent\ttfamily
\color{canvas75}RGB colour canvascolor!75!white\\
html : \convertcolorspec{named}{canvas75}{HTML}\HTMLcolour
\HTMLcolour\\
cmyk : \convertcolorspec{named}{canvas75}{cmyk}\CMYKcolour
\CMYKcolour

\end{document}
```

[image]