# Is there LaTeX code to convert % based rgb to 0-255 based RGB color codes?

Tags: color, convert

I have **hundreds** of mixed color definitions in my project that use three different color coding styles, e.g. (% based) **rgb**, (0-255 based) **RGB**, and (FFFFFF) **HTML** :

```
\definecolor{lemon}{rgb}{1.0, 0.97, 0.0}
\definecolor{maize}{rgb}{0.98, 0.93, 0.37}
\definecolor{mustard}{rgb}{1.0, 0.86, 0.35}
\definecolor{ocre}{HTML}{F16723}
\definecolor{Tangerine}{RGB}{253,128,8}
```

In a housekeeping move, as a way to sort my colors according to their numeric codes, I'm wondering if there might be LaTeX code already out in the ether that I could use to convert the (% based) **rgb** color definitions to (0-255 based) **RGB** color definitions, e.g. to convert:

```
\definecolor{maize}{rgb}{0.98, 0.93, 0.37}
```

to:

```
\definecolor{maize}{RGB}{250,237,94}
```

Ideally, the code would then write out the LaTeX code for the converted colors in (0-255 based) **RGB** color (LaTeX) code into a text file.

If such LaTeX code exists, I could then use the LaTeX (% based) **rgb** to (0-255 based) **RGB** conversion code as a model to create LaTeX code to convert HTML colors **TO** (0-255 based) **RGB** colors.

Once all the colors have been converted to (0-255 based) **RGB** colors, I could then sort all the color definitions numerically by their (0-255 based) **RGB** colors.

Comment: This is very similar in nature to [Figuring out RGB or HEX color from xcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35033/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: Apologies for not being more specific ... I'd like to start with an input text file that contains all (but just) the LaTeX color definitions therein. Then run a (presumably) small LaTeX project that would then read the input text file, convert the color definitions from (% based) rgb color definitions TO (0-255 based) RGB color definitions, and write out the LaTeX code for the converted color definitions in (0-255 based) RGB color (LaTeX) code into an output text file. Does that clarify the work flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example code redefines `\definecolor{<colour>}{<model>}{<spec>}` so that it can output an updated `\definecolor{<colour>}{RGB}{<RGB spec>}` to a file called `colour.txt` (thanks to [Figuring out RGB or HEX color from `xcolor`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35033/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newfile}

\newoutputstream{colourfile}
\openoutputfile{colour.txt}{colourfile}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\olddefinecolor\definecolor
\renewcommand{\definecolor}[3]{%
  \olddefinecolor{#1}{#2}{#3}% Original colour definition
  % Taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35033/5764
  \extractcolorspec{#1}{\tempcolourspec}% Extract colour specification
  \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tempcolourspec{RGB}\tempcolourspec% Convert colour specification to RGB
  \addtostream{colourfile}{% Write RGB colour specification to file
    \protect\definecolor{#1}{RGB}{\tempcolourspec}%
  }%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeoutputstream{colourfile}% Close colour.txt
}

\definecolor{lemon}{rgb}{1.0, 0.97, 0.0}
\definecolor{maize}{rgb}{0.98, 0.93, 0.37}
\definecolor{mustard}{rgb}{1.0, 0.86, 0.35}
\definecolor{ocre}{HTML}{F16723}
\definecolor{Tangerine}{RGB}{253,128,8}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{lemon}{lemon}
\textcolor{maize}{maize}
\textcolor{mustard}{mustard}
\textcolor{ocre}{ocre}
\textcolor{Tangerine}{Tangerine}

\end{document}
```

The file `colour.txt` now contains:

```
\definecolor{lemon}{RGB}{255,247,0}
\definecolor{maize}{RGB}{250,237,94}
\definecolor{mustard}{RGB}{255,219,89}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{241,103,35}
\definecolor{Tangerine}{RGB}{253,128,8}
```

Comment: Wow ... you answered my question BEFORE I even finished adding my specific comment ... I've added ALL of my color definitions to you code ... and POW ... they're all redefined ... INCLUDING the HTML colors ... Thank you ... I've accepted your answer, but I also tried to change the code:     \protect\definecolor{#1}{RGB}{\tempcolourspec}% to
    \protect\definecolor{\textcolor{#1}{#1}}{RGB}{\tempcolourspec}%
in an attempt to actually color the defined color that appears immediately after \definecolor.  It did NOT work ... something about \leavevmode appeared after \definecolor ... THANK YOU !

Comment: @ Werner - Using the \color command in lieu of \textcolor, and a bit of manual adjustments (actually more than a bit), I've been able to color all of the colors, e.g. \definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{241,103,35} for example to provide a sample of each color. It would have taken me MUCH longer to do so w/o Werner's code ... Thank you ... and in doing so, I discovered a few colors that were mis-coded incorrectly - a side benefit I did not anticipate, Thank you!